# Using multiple ad networks

Tags: java, android, webview, admob, leadbolt

I just implemented the ad-network, Leadbolt, into my android application. Im using the HTML Banner as my adtype. And I would like some kind of fallback solution if Leadbolt fails to load use Admob instead etc.

Bringing Leadbolt html ads is done via a webview and you pass in a URL to the webview and the ad is shown within.

This is the code:

```
wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
wv.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
String html = "MY_ID";
wv.loadData(html, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

I also have set my Webview (wv) set on: setWebViewClient, so I get callbacks but **even** if I dont have any internet connection I get the callback OnPageFinished so im unable to se if my ad has loaded or what has been done.

Does anyone have any advice how to do this, to help me with a fallback solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check your www.adwhirl.com
With the SDK and homepage you can create new "Apps" with a fallback hierarchy. All you need to do is, create a custom event on adwhirl, implement the method for calling your ads on leadbolt add your publisher id to admob settings and set up the fallback hierarchy.

Hope this helps. Good luck.